# NullPinterException while writing in Hadoop tmp file

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, tmp

Below is code snippet where goal is to  write some files in hadoop /tmp directory but getting NullPointerException(as not hadoop not able to create the directory or write  inside /tmp direcoty) I am using single user so no permission issues are there and given chmod 777  to /tmp directory.

```
public static class BigBWAMap extends 
        Mapper<Object,Text,IntWritable,Text>
File fout;
FileOutputStream fos;
BufferedWriter bw;
String tmpFileString = "";
String[] values1;
String[] values2;
String tmpDir;
//setup method
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        tmpDir = conf.get("hadoop.tmp.dir","/tmp/");

    if(tmpDir == null || tmpDir.isEmpty()) {
        tmpDir = "/tmp/";
    }
    tmpFileString = tmpDir+"/HadoopTMPFile-"1"-"+213"; // directory where to write:  /tmp/HadoopTMPFile-1-213
    fout = new File(tmpFileString);

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

} 

}
```

Getting NullPointerException at bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
 and that due to as /tmp/HadoopTMPFile-1-213 not writable. Even if I  try to write to /tmp only getting same NPE.

Comment: If the FileNotFoundException is executed, then `fos` is `null`, so put the `bw` in the `try`

Comment: Done this time Map reduce program ran sucessfully but no output file generated in hdfs. Also  instead of getting NullPointerException on terminal getting same now in log file now ,also stack trace  is not coming after  making this change.

Comment: Actually the java program is unable to create the directory/file in hadoop localfile system with file path specified by  varaiable tmpFileString.tmpFileString = tmpDir+"/HadoopTMPFile-"1"-"+213"; // directory where to write:  /tmp/HadoopTMPFile-1-213
    fout = new File(tmpFileString); // Hence getting   exception here.